# Swift 2.0: Protocol extensions: Two protocols with the same function signature compile error

Tags: swift, swift2

Given the two protocols and their extensions:

```
protocol FirstDelegate {
    func someFunc()
}

protocol SecondDelegate {
    func someFunc()
}

extension FirstDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
        print("First delegate")
    }
}

extension SecondDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
        print("Second delegate")
    }
}
```

and trying to conform to both of them:

```
class SomeClass: FirstDelegate, SecondDelegate {}
```

I receive compile-time error:

> Type 'SomeClass' does not conform to protocol 'FirstDelegate'

Exchanging `FirstDelegate` and `SecondDelegate`:

```
class SomeClass: SecondDelegate, FirstDelegate {}
```

produces reverse:

> Type 'SomeClass' does not conform to protocol 'SecondDelegate'

Removing one of the extensions resolves the problem. Ditto providing implementation for `someFunc()` inside `SomeClass`.

This protocol extension functionality is rather new to me. Also the information about it in an Apple's official 'Swift Programming Guide (Prerelease)' is scarce at the moment.

Did I violate some rules of protocol extensions here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Which of the both methods would you expect to be called by `SomeClass().someFunc()` ?

Comment: I'm playing with protocol extensions and their syntax. By that I'm trying to understand their rules and behaviour.

Comment: @mesmerizingsnow Well it doesn't really make sense for two protocols to have the exact same method, then you wouldn't need two protocols because they're just the same...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A protocol defines requirements (methods, properties, ...) for a 
conformant type.

```
protocol FirstDelegate {
    func someFunc()
}

protocol SecondDelegate {
    func someFunc()
}
```

defines two protocols with the same required method `someFunc()`. 
A conformant type must implement this method:

```
class SomeClass: FirstDelegate, SecondDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
        print("SomeClass implementation")
    }
}
```

A *protocol extension* provides method and property implementations
to conformant types. A special case of a protocol extension is a
*default implementation*, which is what you defined here:

```
extension FirstDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
        print("First delegate")
    }
}
```

It defines a default implementation of `someFunc()` for all types
conforming to `FirstDelegate`. Since this is the *only* required
method of that protocol, a conforming class need not define the
method at all:

```
class SomeClass: FirstDelegate {

}

SomeClass().someFunc() // Output: First delegate
```

But *if* the class provides its own implementation then that
will be used:

```
class SomeClass: FirstDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
        print("SomeClass implementation")
    }
}

SomeClass().someFunc() // Output: SomeClass implementation
```

In your case, you have defined default implementations of `someFunc()`
for *both* protocols:

```
extension FirstDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
        print("First delegate")
    }
}

extension SecondDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
        print("Second delegate")
    }
}
```

A class can still conform to both protocols if it provides its own
implementation of the required method:

```
class SomeClass: FirstDelegate, SecondDelegate {
    func someFunc() {
        print("SomeClass implementation")
    }
}
```

But the class *cannot* conform by using the default implementation

```
class SomeClass: FirstDelegate, SecondDelegate {

}
```

for both protocols
because there is a *conflict*. It is unspecified which default
implementation should be used, and that's why the compiler complains.

Actually the class now conforms to *none* of the protocols.
This can be seen in the full compiler log in the Report navigator:

```
main.swift:24:7: error: type 'SomeClass' does not conform to protocol 'FirstDelegate'
class SomeClass: FirstDelegate, SecondDelegate {
      ^
main.swift:5:10: note: multiple matching functions named 'someFunc()' with type '() -> ()'
    func someFunc()
         ^
main.swift:19:10: note: candidate exactly matches
    func someFunc() {
         ^
main.swift:13:10: note: candidate exactly matches
    func someFunc() {
         ^
main.swift:24:7: error: type 'SomeClass' does not conform to protocol 'SecondDelegate'
class SomeClass: FirstDelegate, SecondDelegate {
      ^
main.swift:9:10: note: multiple matching functions named 'someFunc()' with type '() -> ()'
    func someFunc()
         ^
main.swift:19:10: note: candidate exactly matches
    func someFunc() {
         ^
main.swift:13:10: note: candidate exactly matches
    func someFunc() {
         ^
```

Comment: Is it possible (if you wanted to) to reuse either one of the default implementations explicitly, then inside forcibly implemented class function, without having to (although not necessarily) duplicate code please?