# How do you disambiguate between static methods from implemented protocols?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, default-implementation

Casting works just fine for instance functions.

```
protocol Protocol1 {}
extension Protocol1 {
    func instanceFunc() {}
    static func staticFunc() {}
}

protocol Protocol2 {}
extension Protocol2 {
    func instanceFunc() {}
    static func staticFunc() {}
}

struct Struct: Protocol1, Protocol2 {
    func instanceFunc() {
        (self as Protocol1).instanceFunc()
        (self as Protocol2).instanceFunc()
    }

    static func staticFunc() {
        // My best guess. Nope!
        (Struct as Protocol1.Type).staticFunc()
        (Struct as Protocol2.Type).staticFunc()
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586864/swift-2-0-protocol-extensions-two-protocols-with-the-same-function-signature-c

Comment: I understand that, as well as that protocols have an identity crisis as to whether they represent the interface of an object, or a certain personality of it, but given that the personality can be manually selected for instance functions, the same should be possible for static whatevers.

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that Struct is not an object, but you are trying to cast like it is.  Are you getting an error like constructor call after type name is expected?

Comment: I'm not trying to cast an instance like anything. I'm guessing at what the syntax might be for doing what I want to do.

Comment: What I am saying is you do not need to be casting  you just call Protocol1.staticFunc() and Protocol2.staticFunc() because it is not an object, they are static functions attached to the class.

Comment: You do not understand that I know what a static method is. You are not yet accustomed to Swift's static protocol methods, which do not exist in C#. Please try this thing you are suggesting, in a Playground, in order to come to the question I have here, instead of an answer to a question I am not asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick mate

```
protocol Protocol1 {}
extension Protocol1 {
    func instanceFunc() {}
    static func staticFunc() {}
}

protocol Protocol2 {}
extension Protocol2 {
    func instanceFunc() {}
    static func staticFunc() {}
}

struct Struct: Protocol1, Protocol2 {
    func instanceFunc() {
        (self as Protocol1).instanceFunc()
        (self as Protocol2).instanceFunc()
    }

    static func staticFunc() {
        (Struct.self as Protocol1.Type).staticFunc()
        (Struct.self as Protocol2.Type).staticFunc()
    }
}
```

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried that; guess not! Good job! Who are you? I'd like to follow your goings-on.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm afraid there's not much to follow though, I'm just trying to help people here and occasionally on swift's subreddit. Throw me a private message there if you need anything.