# Would I run into any problems with having protocols with shared requirements?

Tags: swift, protocols, composition, swift-protocols

```
protocol House {
    var name : String {get set}
    func changeAddress()
}

protocol Person {
    var name : String {get set}
    func changeAddress()
}

class Something : Person, House {
    var name : String

    init (name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
    func changeAddress(){

    }
}
```

Likely I'm not going to do anything like this. But I'm asking this question because I'm getting no warning or anything for this. Isn't this a bug? ie the protocol witness table is conforming to two requirements through one conformance and it's hiding some of its variables, had I just changed the variable to something `id` on one of the protocols then the requirements would have been different, doesn't this at least merit a warning? and then maybe having it silenced by something like `@sharedPWT` :D

Isn't this code smell in it's nature? Or there are circumstances where this can actually be helpful?

Comment: Related: [Swift 2.0: Protocol extensions: Two protocols with the same function signature compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31586864/1187415).

Comment: As matt says, this is perfectly legitimate. For example, in the stdlib both `SetAlgebra` and `Collection` have an `var isEmpty: Bool { get }` is requirement. `Set` conforms to both `SetAlgebra` and `Collection` and satisfies the requirement with its implementation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your witness table idea is a red herring because there is no code and no dispatch. It’s much simpler than that. Both protocols are merely instructions on how to construct an adopting type; they say “do this” and in your adopter you do that, so you conform to both requirements. No problem.

If these were methods with extensions and implementations, now we’d have something to talk about! For example:

```
protocol A {
    func f()
}
extension A {
    func f() { print("A")}
}
protocol B {
    func f()
}
extension B {
    func f() { print("B")}
}
class C:A,B {} // compiler stops you, rightly
```

> Isn't this code smell in it's nature? Or there are circumstances where this can actually be helpful?

It’s not a bad smell, and in fact in a very real sense this kind of thing happens all the time throughout the standard library. After all, what's the protocol hierarchy but an example of the very thing you're outlining? To say that protocol P2 adopts protocol P1 is just a shorthand for saying that whatever P1 requires, P2 also requires.

Comment: please see my edit. _Both protocols say “do this” and you do_ The meaning is of _do this_ is contextual. To me it's not transparent...Also can you share examples of standard library which do the same...

Comment: Still no extension implementation for the protocols so still no dispatch and no issue. Example from the standard library, ask yourself what protocol hierarchy is.

Comment: My question is would I ever run into an issue? Your answer seems to be _with extensions and implementations_ there is a chance of issues. Can you give an example? Because I'm not following

Comment: And I'm saying no you never would, not as you're posing the case.

Comment: Thanks. I see, so as long as there's a single point of adoption then things are good? As for protocol hierarchy, I like your suggestion of asking myself. I did that. I guess I'm not bright enough. I went to [Swiftdoc: Int](https://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/int/) and clicked on the protocol hierarchy of `Int`. Should I be looking into Equatable and Hashable and see if they have shared requirements? **Or is it essentially that for the inherited essentially there isn't a difference between protocol composition vs. inheritance**. For inheritance it makes sense. For composition it seems different.